# Swapping React Contexts in & out of React Components

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Imagine you build Context A and React Components 1 and 1.1, where the latter component is the child of the former.  Everything works perfectly.

Now you build Context B and wish to use Component 1.1 with it.  Given that in Component 1.1 you probably accessed Context A (ie. took advantage of the power of contexts to avoid prop drilling), is there a way to somehow modify things such that the component will work with both Context A and Context B?

I'm thinking/hoping there's some way to dynamically specify which Context to use rather than hard-coding it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import { ContextA } from 'wherever/a';
import { ContextB } from 'wherever/b';

// ...

render() {
  let Context = ContextA;
  if (condition) {
    Context = ContextB;
  }

  return (
    <Context.Consumer>
      {value => <div>Got {value}</div>}
    </Context.Consumer>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

At least with newer versions of React, you can consume multiple contexts easily with the `useContext` hook.

```
import { ContextA } from 'wherever/a';
import { ContextB } from 'wherever/b';

const Child = ({condition}) => {
  let valueA = useContext(ContextA);
  let valueB = useContext(ContextB);

  return (
    <div>Got {condition ? valueA : valueB}</div>
  );
}

render(
  <ContextA.Provider value={something}>
    <ContextB.Provider value={something}>
      <Child />
    <ContextB.Provider />
  <ContextA.Provider />
);
```

Comment: Interesting but I don't like the pattern of intermixing two contexts throughout the code.

Comment: The most idiomatic way would probably be to define two separate components that each use only one context and conditionally rendering one or the other.

Comment: In practice my child component is an `AddUser` component.  As mentioned previously, it works perfectly with Context A.  I'd now like to use it with a different parent component and a different Context.  The notion of having to make a copy of `AddUser` simply to work with these other things would be a very bad practice.

Comment: @robertwerner-goodyear If your `AddUser` component relies on the context and you want to use another context, maybe you should extract this logic to the parent component, and pass down the correct behavior to the `AddUser` component

Comment: Or if any suitable context will do, just pass the context object as a prop. Lots of options.